# Volley request doesn't work in android api 19

Tags: android, android-volley

I'm trying to check a number in the server database with the volley .so  I do not have any problem in Android Lollipop and above versions, I get result correctly but when I use KitKat version I don't get any result.
How can I fix it?

implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'

```
public class ChknumModel implements ChknumPre {

    ChknumView _view;
    Context _context;

    public ChknumModel(ChknumView view,Context context){this._view = view;this._context = context;}

    @Override
    public void checknumber(String number) {
            RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(_context);
            StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET,
                    DirectionU.BASE_URL_USERS + "chknumber/" + number + "/",
                    new Response.Listener<String>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(String response) {

                            if(response.equals("found_number"))
                                _view.found_number();
                            else
                                _view.not_found_number();
                        }
                    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    VolleyLog.d("chknumber","error is " + error.getMessage());
                }
            });

        request.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(
                50000,
                DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
                DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));

            queue.add(request);
    }
}
```

Comment: Also post your logs

Comment: @Swati there is no display in the log. volley send request continual but I don't get any result in the log

Comment: Check this--> https://github.com/google/volley/issues/134

Comment: @Swati yeah. the problem is from the SSL. thank u